# Error #3675: Texture format mismatch. in Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, starling-framework

I use Starling 1.6 with Adobe AIR 17.0
And now this error just jumps from no place(previous version runs well). It happens before the AssetManager load done.

Even if I just use this simple code:

```
var bgTexture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmapData(new EMBED(), false, false, scale);
```

The error in this line:

```
fromBitmapData(bitmap.bitmapData, generateMipMaps, optimizeForRenderToTexture, scale, format, repeat)
format = "bgra";
generateMipMaps = false;
optimizeForRenderToTexture = false;
scale = 2;
```

This error happens! I follow the starling scaffow-mobile project.

Can you please help me explain and guide me how to solve this? Ask if you need any more detail please.

Comment: Please read community forum http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/error-3675-texture-format-mismatch, no one really sure about this error, but you can find some way for experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Use Texture.fromBitmap(); 
instead of Texture.fromBitmapData()